# Trying to join elements of XML with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery, sql-server-2019

I have this following query.

The RDBMS is Microsoft SQL Server 2019 Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0

I'm trying to join XML elements using SQL with no success.

I want to get all nodes of custom_rules element joined with their Translations which are in the bottom of the XML.

The join is based on CustomRule CGID attribute that matches with element ID of element Captions.

When I make the join the joined column returns Null

```
DECLARE @xml as xml = N'
        <BRDatasetNode RootNodeType="Entersoft.Framework.Platform.CustomCommands.BRDatasetNode, ESCustomNode" Version="2" CGID="42d7a588-adb7-4bf1-8ed0-fdefe8038267" Dataset="ESGOPerson">
          <system_rules CGID="beeeb555-749a-411d-8021-5ef9d521ad8e" />
          <custom_rules CGID="13758bd2-68c0-4f52-b78e-80825016c77b">
            <CustomRule CGID="e7d23139-6880-41b0-b8c6-22212a510108" use_case="bf5c89d2-93d9-4ea7-858f-bba9fdf0d957">
            </CustomRule>
            <CustomRule CGID="491bfdbc-58ab-41c7-8915-d94a51b55d26">
            </CustomRule>
          </custom_rules>
          <Translations>
            <ESCaptionsDS>
          <Captions>
            <ID>e7d23139-6880-41b0-b8c6-22212a510108</ID>
            <Suffix>Title</Suffix>
            <LangID>el</LangID>
            <Caption>Κανόνες για επωφελούμενα πρόσωπα</Caption>
          </Captions>
          <Captions>
            <ID>491bfdbc-58ab-41c7-8915-d94a51b55d26</ID>
            <Suffix>Title</Suffix>
            <LangID>el</LangID>
            <Caption>Ανάθεση Ημ/νίας εγγραφής</Caption>
          </Captions>
        </ESCaptionsDS>
          </Translations>
        </BRDatasetNode>'
        
        
SELECT
    CAST(u.n.value('@CGID', 'varchar(max)') AS varchar(max)) , zz.Caption 
FROM
    @xml.nodes('/BRDatasetNode/custom_rules/CustomRule') AS u (n)       
CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT
         CAST(u.n.value('Caption[1]', 'varchar(max)') AS varchar(max)) as Caption
     FROM
         @xml.nodes('/BRDatasetNode/Translations/ESCaptionsDS/Captions') AS z (n) 
     WHERE
         CONVERT(nvarchar(max), z.n.value('ID[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')) = CONVERT(nvarchar(max), u.n.value('./@CGID', 'nvarchar(max)'))
    ) AS zz
```

The result is

| (No column name) | Caption |
| --- | --- |
| e7d23139-6880-41b0-b8c6-22212a510108 | NULL |
| 491bfdbc-58ab-41c7-8915-d94a51b55d26 | NULL |

Comment: XML support is very vendor dependent. So knowing the DBMS is vital. [Edit] your question and tag your DBMS. And while you're at it, try to minimize your example to make it easier to understand and help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following solution for MS SQL Server.

It is using XQuery and its FLWOR expression for the join.

The actual join is implemented for two sequences: `$x` and `$y`.

The CTE returns relevant `<Captions>` elements.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @xml XML = 
N'<BRDatasetNode RootNodeType="Entersoft.Framework.Platform.CustomCommands.BRDatasetNode, ESCustomNode"
               Version="2" CGID="42d7a588-adb7-4bf1-8ed0-fdefe8038267"
               Dataset="ESGOPerson">
    <system_rules CGID="beeeb555-749a-411d-8021-5ef9d521ad8e"/>
    <custom_rules CGID="13758bd2-68c0-4f52-b78e-80825016c77b">
        <CustomRule CGID="e7d23139-6880-41b0-b8c6-22212a510108"
                    use_case="bf5c89d2-93d9-4ea7-858f-bba9fdf0d957">
        </CustomRule>
        <CustomRule CGID="491bfdbc-58ab-41c7-8915-d94a51b55d26">
        </CustomRule>
        <CustomRule CGID="577f5ec8-5058-490a-98b4-f87b663f3b67">
        </CustomRule>
        <CustomRule CGID="70e93dee-051f-40fd-bbb1-b60d084e0cb0">
        </CustomRule>
    </custom_rules>
    <Translations>
        <ESCaptionsDS>
            <Captions>
                <ID>e7d23139-6880-41b0-b8c6-22212a510108</ID>
                <Suffix>Title</Suffix>
                <LangID>el</LangID>
                <Caption>Κανόνες για επωφελούμενα πρόσωπα</Caption>
            </Captions>
            <Captions>
                <ID>ffeee6da-5239-484a-b701-ce9d1ab7b05f</ID>
                <Suffix>Title</Suffix>
                <LangID>el</LangID>
                <Caption>Κανόνες για επωφελούμενα πρόσωπα</Caption>
            </Captions>
            <Captions>
                <ID>8bae1ba8-e6ed-4e0a-b02d-1f3e73034801</ID>
                <Suffix>Title</Suffix>
                <LangID>el</LangID>
                <Caption>Ανάθεση πεδίων κατά την επισύναψη εγγράφου</Caption>
            </Captions>
            <Captions>
                <ID>b85f3890-bcd9-43a4-8619-a061a97c9747</ID>
                <Suffix>Title</Suffix>
                <LangID>el</LangID>
                <Caption>Ανάθεση πεδίων κατά την επισύναψη εγγράφου</Caption>
            </Captions>
            <Captions>
                <ID>722e1fce-8d04-4f61-9272-e31bce9f984f</ID>
                <Suffix>Title</Suffix>
                <LangID>el</LangID>
                <Caption>Maximum Entries</Caption>
            </Captions>
            <Captions>
                <ID>1c614046-c7c5-4dd3-87d0-dabec01c15ab</ID>
                <Suffix>Title</Suffix>
                <LangID>el</LangID>
                <Caption>Ενημέρωση χαρακτηρισμού ανήλικος</Caption>
            </Captions>
            <Captions>
                <ID>09436c79-3bf0-4c46-80fb-93a20e1e7924</ID>
                <Suffix>Title</Suffix>
                <LangID>el</LangID>
                <Caption>Ενημέρωση χαρακτηρισμού ανήλικος</Caption>
            </Captions>
            <Captions>
                <ID>d9575b83-fa08-4022-a54a-7633ea802fc0</ID>
                <Suffix>Title</Suffix>
                <LangID>el</LangID>
                <Caption>Maximum Entries</Caption>
            </Captions>
            <Captions>
                <ID>ad7e28a5-3366-4487-bc99-06b018e29609</ID>
                <Suffix>Title</Suffix>
                <LangID>el</LangID>
                <Caption>Έλεγχος συμπλήρωσης Φορέα</Caption>
            </Captions>
            <Captions>
                <ID>23c54352-3496-45f4-9551-45f7a29056f0</ID>
                <Suffix>Message</Suffix>
                <LangID>el</LangID>
                <Caption>Παρακαλώ συμπληρώστε Φορέα.</Caption>
            </Captions>
            <Captions>
                <ID>a0903e5a-dc7b-40d7-bef1-ada1af724243</ID>
                <Suffix>Title</Suffix>
                <LangID>el</LangID>
                <Caption>Κανόνες για επωφελούμενα πρόσωπα</Caption>
            </Captions>
            <Captions>
                <ID>491bfdbc-58ab-41c7-8915-d94a51b55d26</ID>
                <Suffix>Title</Suffix>
                <LangID>el</LangID>
                <Caption>Ανάθεση Ημ/νίας εγγραφής</Caption>
            </Captions>
            <Captions>
                <ID>96c844ac-41be-4fe1-8c54-360c830351f1</ID>
                <Suffix>Title</Suffix>
                <LangID>el</LangID>
                <Caption>Ανάθεση Ημ/νίας εγγραφής</Caption>
            </Captions>
            <Captions>
                <ID>0c08d413-0c08-4bb5-96a7-93322fdfd955</ID>
                <Suffix>Title</Suffix>
                <LangID>el</LangID>
                <Caption>Ανάθεση Ημ/νίας εγγραφής</Caption>
            </Captions>
            <Captions>
                <ID>9cab91d1-202d-490e-8ee2-4fee30db56d2</ID>
                <Suffix>Title</Suffix>
                <LangID>el</LangID>
                <Caption>Ανάθεση Ημ/νίας εγγραφής</Caption>
            </Captions>
            <Captions>
                <ID>9a865e63-0605-49a3-aa03-08504831e136</ID>
                <Suffix>Title</Suffix>
                <LangID>el</LangID>
                <Caption>Maximum Entries</Caption>
            </Captions>
            <Captions>
                <ID>65f75065-376d-40f8-9b2a-733bcc597247</ID>
                <Suffix>Title</Suffix>
                <LangID>el</LangID>
                <Caption>Ανάθεση Ημ/νίας εγγραφής</Caption>
            </Captions>
            <Captions>
                <ID>577f5ec8-5058-490a-98b4-f87b663f3b67</ID>
                <Suffix>Title</Suffix>
                <LangID>el</LangID>
                <Caption>Έλεγχος συμπλήρωσης ΑΦΜ</Caption>
            </Captions>
            <Captions>
                <ID>91702e0f-3f55-412d-9cde-c0161d7cfcbf</ID>
                <Suffix>Title</Suffix>
                <LangID>el</LangID>
                <Caption>Έλεγχος συμπλήρωσης ΑΦΜ</Caption>
            </Captions>
            <Captions>
                <ID>5660b621-c7d8-41bf-9526-a880e89e2e09</ID>
                <Suffix>Title</Suffix>
                <LangID>el</LangID>
                <Caption>Έλεγχος συμπλήρωσης ΑΦΜ</Caption>
            </Captions>
            <Captions>
                <ID>96adc51f-177a-41a5-ba95-6ebd3f96d25a</ID>
                <Suffix>Title</Suffix>
                <LangID>el</LangID>
                <Caption>Έλεγχος συμπλήρωσης ΑΦΜ</Caption>
            </Captions>
            <Captions>
                <ID>cecb7870-898f-42bf-a3a0-4d436e72c64b</ID>
                <Suffix>Message</Suffix>
                <LangID>el</LangID>
                <Caption>Παρακαλώ συμπληρώστε ΑΦΜ</Caption>
            </Captions>
            <Captions>
                <ID>5c833d3e-00c9-4f5e-a8b3-3ba533a20a31</ID>
                <Suffix>Title</Suffix>
                <LangID>el</LangID>
                <Caption>Έλεγχος συμπλήρωσης ΑΦΜ</Caption>
            </Captions>
            <Captions>
                <ID>70e93dee-051f-40fd-bbb1-b60d084e0cb0</ID>
                <Suffix>Title</Suffix>
                <LangID>el</LangID>
                <Caption>Έλεγχος στοιχείων καταχώρησης</Caption>
            </Captions>
            <Captions>
                <ID>cfdf614e-0835-425e-ab79-870db327fafa</ID>
                <Suffix>Title</Suffix>
                <LangID>el</LangID>
                <Caption>Ανάθεση Ημ/νίας εγγραφής</Caption>
            </Captions>
            <Captions>
                <ID>ac617fca-5fd3-47d1-909f-131bfb8c7d58</ID>
                <Suffix>Title</Suffix>
                <LangID>el</LangID>
                <Caption>Έλεγχος στοιχείων καταχώρησης</Caption>
            </Captions>
            <Captions>
                <ID>787963fb-304f-4e60-a3b5-0fde2de50ece</ID>
                <Suffix>Title</Suffix>
                <LangID>el</LangID>
                <Caption>Ανάθεση Ημ/νίας εγγραφής</Caption>
            </Captions>
            <Captions>
                <ID>66bc1cd4-a7e2-47e1-b4b9-76276c73480c</ID>
                <Suffix>Message</Suffix>
                <LangID>el</LangID>
                <Caption>Δεν έχετε συμπληρώσει όλα τα πεδία (Επώνυμο, Όνομα, Φύλο, Ημ/νία γέννησης, Αριθμός εγγράφου)</Caption>
            </Captions>
            <Captions>
                <ID>512b35f8-3190-493c-b680-ac8caf713fcb</ID>
                <Suffix>Title</Suffix>
                <LangID>el</LangID>
                <Caption>Ανάθεση Ημ/νίας εγγραφής</Caption>
            </Captions>
        </ESCaptionsDS>
    </Translations>
</BRDatasetNode>';

;WITH rs (xmldata) AS
(
    SELECT @xml.query('
       for $x in /BRDatasetNode/custom_rules/CustomRule/@CGID,
          $y in /BRDatasetNode/Translations/ESCaptionsDS/Captions/ID/text()
       where lower-case($y) eq lower-case($x)
       return /BRDatasetNode/Translations/ESCaptionsDS/Captions[ID/text() = $y]
    ')
)
SELECT c.value('(ID/text())[1]', 'UNIQUEIDENTIFIER') AS ID
    , c.value('(Caption/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(100)') AS Caption
FROM rs CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('/Captions') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+--------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
|                  ID                  |             Caption              |
+--------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
| E7D23139-6880-41B0-B8C6-22212A510108 | Κανόνες για επωφελούμενα πρόσωπα |
| 491BFDBC-58AB-41C7-8915-D94A51B55D26 | Ανάθεση Ημ/νίας εγγραφής         |
| 577F5EC8-5058-490A-98B4-F87B663F3B67 | Έλεγχος συμπλήρωσης ΑΦΜ          |
| 70E93DEE-051F-40FD-BBB1-B60D084E0CB0 | Έλεγχος στοιχείων καταχώρησης    |
+--------------------------------------+----------------------------------+
```

Comment: @TedKonstantoudakis, glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please up-vote: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/38142115-sql-server-vnext-post-2019-and-nosql-functionali

Comment: Is there anyway i can filter A L L descendants child records based on specfic attribute value  and focus on all these records wherever they are found ? ---> Ex. In the where lower-case($y) eq lower-case($x) to put something like  .... and $x//*@Attributename="SampleAttrValue")

Comment: @TedKonstantoudakis, definitely, you can add as many as needed additional conditions to the `where` clause.